# Is it good to exercise class which is injected in the parent?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit

Let's assume I have a `MyServiceTest` class which is extended by some `HelperTest` class which has context configuration defined and injected service like this:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:META-INF/context.xml" })
public abstract class HelperTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;
}
```

This helper class helps test classes to prepare the system for testing.

Now I want to test `MyService` class which means that I need to inject this service in my `MyServiceTest` class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class MyServiceTest extends HelperTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;
}
```

But in general because `MyServiceTest` is inherited I could just define `MyService` in HelperTest as `protected` and use it in `MyService` class.

*Is it right thing to do or there are some other things which might influence when I use bean injection via spring in this way?*

Comment: In unit tests you shouldn't load the spring context, don't use `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` and `@ContextConfiguration(...)`, use a library like mockito or JMockit, mock dependencies and try `MyService` isolated from it's collaborators

Comment: Well, yes, using those is more like integration tests, but this is what I do. I understand that I need to mock dependencies, but I use it more for injected actual class to be tested even though of course I can create it by explicit constructor call.

Comment: :), Otherwise, in your case IMHO I would put `MyService`  in `MyServiceTest` which is the place where you go to test it. Furthermore,  you could put `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` in `HelperTest`. Then you may use these `HelperTest` in other cases or services just inheriting `HelperTest`